# JavaScript Redirect doesn't work windows mobile app

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

Hey guys I have an error when I try to redirect page in windows mobile app:
error:

```
APPHOST9624:The app can't use script to  load the https://google.com url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app.
```

Code that I used in js file:

```
window.open('https://google.com');
```

I also tried to install cordova InAppBrowser plugin, so after my code look like:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicitly call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');
        var ref = window.open('https://google.com', '_self', 'location=no')

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};

app.initialize();
```

But still It doesn't work
Also I've tried:

```
windows.location.href = "https://google.com";
location.href = "https://google.com";
```

I compiled app with cordova, debug in Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: does `window.location="https://google.com"` work for you?

Comment: Nice to know that Microsoft is still doing arbitrary crap with their web platforms.

Comment: I guess it is some kind of an ad blocking mechanism , experienced Windows developer might be able to tell better .

Comment: Look at this from msdn "The app can’t use script to load the url url because the url launches another app. Only direct user interaction can launch another app." : "Apps can't launch other apps directly. Other apps can be launched by the user when the app implements certain contracts. For more info, see App contracts and extensions."

Comment: It seems you're looking for "contracts" http://msdn.developer-works.com/article/11335550/JavaScript+redirect+in+web+context+of+HTML+%26amp%3B+JS+store+app

Comment: To use InAppBrowser to open the url, you need to firstly set window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open; in ondeviceready event.

Comment: @AlanYao-MSFT unfortunately, it still doesn't work

Comment: Could you please share a repro project?

Comment: Did you solve this? Just ran into it now and I haven't found a solution.